# Sort AngularFire2 items in order of creation date

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am new to angular and currently creating a project using Angular2 and Firebase.

I want to be able to sort my database in date created order. However, I am unsure on how I could achieve this. I looked up articles and seen their implementations.
But I do not know how to implement this to my project.

Here is my code that deals with querying. My Firebase database just has title, content and date(I type the date manually).

```
posts: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl:AlertController, angFire: AngularFire) {
this.posts= angFire.database.list('/Post',{
  query:{
    orderByChild: "date"
  }
});
```

Any help would be great, thankyou.

JSON here

```
{`"Post" : {
  "-KYsuclduIKOVi6VXGmn" : {
     "content" : "text goes here",
     "date" : "12/12/16",
     "title" : "Title"
}
```

}
}

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Doesn't it work? Does it return anything? Are the items unsorted? It would probably also help if you share a minimal snippet of the JSON you're trying to display (as text, no screenshot please). You can easily get this by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console.

Comment: Sorry, I want to be able to make a post and have firebase automatically add the date and put it in order of latest date first. (added the JSON)

Comment: Firebase doesn't have an option to automatically add the date on creation, you'll have to do that yourself, but as you're already adding `content` and `title` to your post you can easily add a date as well?
Here's more info on sorting: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data
In your case you can use `orderByChild`. There is no option to "reverse" your order, you'd have to do that yourself (add a `reverse` in code or in template)

Comment: Thanks, i sorted the problem out, it was really easy. I just over thought it and made it more complicated but all i had to do was add one line of code.

Comment: Good to hear that you fixed it. If you could post your solution as an answer, that might be useful to future developer who happen upon this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So all I had to do was add the `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to the date. This adds the timestamp to my firebase database.

```
text:"Save Post",
      handler: data => {
        this.posts.push({
          title: data.title,
          content: data.content,
          date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        })
```